# How to delete all upcoming instances of a repeating event in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have a daily event in Google Calendar that repeats indefinitely. The event was created by someone else from their iCloud Calendar.

I now want to delete all future instance of this event from my calendar, but without deleting all the occurrences in the past.

[**Google Help on removing an event**](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37113?hl=en) says there is an **All following** option.

However, I am only seeing these options:

[image: Google Calendar Delete Event Options]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* that option is only available for the creator of an event. If someone else invites you, you can only delete one instance or all of them.

Answer (score 2):

If the Organizer (typically the creator) of the event has given the quests "Modify event" permission then you can edit the event and remove yourself from it. Once you save the event it would prompt you with the option to "Edit recurring event" this will provide the option "This and following events". Once you have saved the event using that option you will still see the events in the history but no longer in future scheduled events. Unfortunately, this won't work if you have been invited as part of a group and not directly added to the event.